# How to read from standard input line by line?

Tags: java, scala, io, java.util.scanner

What's the Scala recipe for reading line by line from the standard input ? Something like the equivalent java code :

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class ScannerTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The most straight-forward looking approach will just use `readLine()` which is part of `Predef`. however that is rather ugly as you need to check for eventual null value:

```
object ScannerTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var ok = true
    while (ok) {
      val ln = readLine()
      ok = ln != null
      if (ok) println(ln)
    }
  }
}
```

this is so verbose, you'd rather use `java.util.Scanner` instead.

I think a more pretty approach will use `scala.io.Source`:

```
object ScannerTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    for (ln <- io.Source.stdin.getLines) println(ln)
  }
}
```

Comment: the method readLine of Predef was deprecated since 2.11.0, now it's recommended to use the method in `scala.io.StdIn`

Comment: @itemState my program is not ending, if i use,  "io.Source.stdin.getLines" 

going to wait mode ... how do handle this...

Answer (score 54):

For the console you can use `Console.readLine`. You can write (if you want to stop on an empty line):

```
Iterator.continually(Console.readLine).takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).foreach(line => println("read " + line))
```

If you cat a file to generate the input you may need to stop on either null or empty using:

```
@inline def defined(line: String) = {
  line != null && line.nonEmpty
}
Iterator.continually(Console.readLine).takeWhile(defined(_)).foreach(line => println("read " + line))
```

Comment: I know about Console.readLine(), I am looking for a given recipe . The "scala" way for reading line by line from Standard input .

Comment: I think you mean `takeWhile(_ != null)`

Comment: Depends how you want to stop. Looking for an empty line is often the simplest solution.

Comment: Note that from Scala 2.11.0 `Console.readLine` is deprecated, use `StdIn.readline` instead.

Comment: Or `.takeWhile(Option(_).nonEmpty)` might feel better in case you want to avoid the `null` keyword completely.

Answer (score 27):

```
val input = Source.fromInputStream(System.in);
val lines = input.getLines.collect
```

Comment: `io.Source.stdin` is defined (in `scala.io.Source` class) as `def stdin = fromInputStream(System.in)` so probably it's better to stick with the `io.Source.stdin`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Scala 2.12.4, or I didn't find the right things to import.

Comment: It works in Scala 2.12, just that the `collect` method is changed sicne this answer so you have to just call `input.getLines` which gives you an `Iterator`. You can force it to materialize using `.toStream` or `.toList` on it, depends on the use case.

Answer (score 12):

A recursive version (the compiler detects a tail recursion for improved heap usage),

```
def read: Unit = {
  val s = scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
  println(s)
  if (s.isEmpty) () else read 
}
```

Note the use of `io.StdIn` from Scala 2.11 . Also note with this approach we can accumulate user input in a collection that is eventually returned -- in addition to be printed out. Namely,

```
import annotation.tailrec

def read: Seq[String]= {

  @tailrec
  def reread(xs: Seq[String]): Seq[String] = {
    val s = StdIn.readLine()
    println(s)
    if (s.isEmpty()) xs else reread(s +: xs) 
  }

  reread(Seq[String]())
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Can you not use

```
var userinput = readInt // for integers
var userinput = readLine 
...
```

As available here : [Scaladoc API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Console$)

Comment: this is not equivalent to the presented code with loop

Answer (score 2):

As noted briefly in other comments, [`scala.Predef.readLine()` is deprecated](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.Predef$) since Scala 2.11.0, and you can replace it with [`scala.io.StdIn.readLine()`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.1/scala/io/StdIn$.html):

```scala
// Read STDIN lines until a blank one
import scala.io.StdIn.readLine

var line = ""
do {
  line = readLine()
  println("Read: " + line)
} while (line != "")
```